# Is it always necessary to select foreign-key related element on create in .NET core

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a one to many relationship between my table Status and StatusText where one Status is only linked to one StatusText, but one StatusText is linked to many Statuses.

DB setup:

```
DeliveryStatus:
 int DeliveryId FK NN,
 int StatusCode FK NN,
 Date StatusTime FK NN,
 Foreignkey StatusCode REFERENCES StatusText(StatusCode);

DeliveryStatusText:
 int StatusCode FK NN,
 varchar StatusText NN;
```

This is how is set it up in .NET Core:

```
public class DeliveryStatus
{
    public int DeliveryId { get; set; }
    public DateTime StatusTime { get; set; }
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("StatusCode")]
    virtual public DeliveryStatusText? DeliveryStatusText { get; set; }

}

public class DeliveryStatusText
{
    [Key]
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }
    public string StatusText { get; set; }

}
```

It seems like I have to find the right DeliveryStatusText from the DB, although setting the StatusCode should be more than sufficient. Is there any ways to skip this db query?

This is how i currently creates a new Status, but I want to get rid of the last line.

```
DeliveryStatus status = new DeliveryStatus();
status.DeliveryId = newDelivery.DeliveryId;
status.StatusCode = 0;
status.StatusTime = DateTime.Now;
status.DeliveryStatusText = await _db.DeliveryStatusText.FindAsync(0); <-- I want to get rid of this line
```

Even tough its marginal, having to find StatusCode from the db seems to put unnecessary stress on the db. Creating a new Status does not require it to immidiatly return a DeliveryStatus.

Answer (score 0):

It's enough that you set the foreign key property "StatusCode". In the code you showed you set both the navigation property "DeliveryStatusText " and "StatusCode"

I took your classes and reproduced this situation in the .NET Core 5.0 console app with MS SQL provider for EF Core. It worked fine after removing the line you pointed out that you'd like to get rid of.

```
var status = new DeliveryStatus();
status.DeliveryId = newDelivery.DeliveryId;
status.StatusCode = 1;
status.StatusTime = DateTime.Now;

context.Add(status);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Additional small remark - you can change [ForeignKey("StatusCode")] into [ForeignKey(nameof(StatusCode))] in the model. It's better to avoid string literals in such places. If someone changes the name of the StatusCode property he can forget about the annotation and if you use nameof, he won't cause the code isn't going to compile.

Comment: Yes my code works and I found out why it didn't. I gave the first row in DeliveryStatusCode StatusId = 0 which messes everything up because asp .net doesn't want to search for. Also thanks for the second tip!

Comment: @Kristoffervt Yeah, that makes sense. When I use MS SQL provider for EF Core I always see IDs greater or equal to 1, never 0. Glad that you solved the problem!